# How do I copy files to folders depending on file name in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

For example, I have the following directories:

```
C:\test\folder100
C:\test\folder101
C:\test\folder102
```

I also have the following files:

```
C:\test\file100.txt
C:\test\file101.txt
C:\test\file102.txt
```

My question comes when I'm trying to figure out a way to copy `file100.txt` to directory `folder100`, `file101.txt` to directory `folder101`, and so on.

I can easily write a simple code to just copy each text file to its pertaining folder, but since I have many directories and files that I want to apply this to, there has to be a way to loop this task, I just can't wrap my head around this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Will it **always** follow the format of `fileXXX` and `folderXXX`? What happens when `XXX` becomes `XXXX`?

Comment: @freefaller Yes, it will always follow that format. It will always be `xxx`.

Comment: are you still needing help, or are the answers provided enough for you to get along with? If so, you should consider marking the one which helped as answered, so we know your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines may be helpful:

```
Private Function GetFolderPath(ByVal filePath As String) As String
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)
    Dim folderName As String = fileName.Substring("file".Length)
    Return Path.Combine("C:\test", folderName)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim mydir As New DirectoryInfo("c:\Mydir\")
    For Each myfile As FileInfo In mydir.GetFiles
        Dim newpath As String = myfile.FullName.Substring(0, myfile.Name.Length - myfile.Extension.Length)
        If New DirectoryInfo(newpath).Exists Then
            myfile.CopyTo(newpath)
        Else
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath)
            myfile.CopyTo(newpath)
        End If
    Next
```